# External Linkage on Static Function Template Arguments

Tags: c++, templates, g++

I'm having trouble finding why the following very small program doesn't compile:

```
#include <stdint.h>

// Returns the alpha value of a texel at position (x, y) from src.
static inline uint8_t get_alpha(const uint8_t *src, int rowBytes, int x, int y) {
    return *(src + y*rowBytes + x);
}

typedef uint8_t (*GetAlphaProc)(const uint8_t* src, int rowBytes, int x, int y);

template<GetAlphaProc getAlphaProc>
static void compress_block(uint8_t** dst, const uint8_t* src, int rowBytes) {
    // Do some trivial stuff
    uint64_t out = 0x0000000001FE000173ULL;
    uint8_t a = getAlphaProc(src, rowBytes, 0, 0);
    *(reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(*dst)) = (static_cast<uint64_t>(a) << 32) | out;
}

int main() {
    // Initialization 
    uint8_t src[144]; for (int i = 0; i < 144; ++i) src[i] = i;
    uint64_t out;
    uint64_t* dst = &out;
    uint8_t** dstPtr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t**>(&dst);

    compress_block<get_alpha>(dstPtr, src, 12);
}
```

The errors that are being produced are:

```
[user ~/test]$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[user ~/test]$ g++ test-linkage.cpp -o testl
test-linkage.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test-linkage.cpp:25:46: error: ‘get_alpha’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘uint8_t (*)(const uint8_t*, int, int, int) {aka unsigned char (*)(const unsigned char*, int, int, int)}’ because function ‘uint8_t get_alpha(const uint8_t*, int, int, int)’ has not external linkage
test-linkage.cpp:25:46: error: no matching function for call to ‘compress_block(uint8_t**&, uint8_t [144], int)’
test-linkage.cpp:25:46: note: candidate is:
test-linkage.cpp:11:13: note: template<uint8_t (* getAlphaProc)(const uint8_t*, int, int, int)> void compress_block(uint8_t**, const uint8_t*, int)
```

The question is why the error `has not external linkage` matters for g++? All of the functions involved in this code have internal storage, and from most of the documentation that I was able to google, this is allowed for static functions. How come function template arguments must have external linkage when being compiled in a single module?

### EDIT

Similar build problems under clang++:

```
[user ~/test]$ clang++ --version
Ubuntu clang version 3.0-6ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_30/final) (based on LLVM 3.0)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix

[user ~/test]$ clang++ -std=c++11 test-linkage.cpp -o testl
test-linkage.cpp:25:5: error: no matching function for call to 'compress_block'
    compress_block<get_alpha>(dstPtr, src, 12);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test-linkage.cpp:11:13: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'getAlphaProc'
static void compress_block(uint8_t** dst, const uint8_t* src, int rowBytes) {
            ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: This `g++ 4.6.3` should be emphasized maybe. @mokosha Get a newer compiler.

Comment: Is my version of clang too old, too?

Comment: @Mokosha I don't know for sure, I don't have that version installed, but the one I do have (clang 3.4.2) accepts it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simply used to be a hard rule, no exceptions, that template arguments could not have internal linkage. It was a hard rule because there was not yet enough implementation experience to tell where it would be okay to have such template arguments.

In C++11, that changed, because we now know that compilers can handle that without much of a problem. Template arguments can now have internal linkage. To compile in C++11 mode, pass `-std=c++11` to the command-line arguments, or `-std=gnu++11` to keep some more extensions enabled.

Note that millsj's answer correctly points out a different problem in your code, and fixing the one you're asking about will make GCC report that too.

Comment: Seems [this sample](http://ideone.com/JASzJk) disproves what you're saying. There's the `std=c++11` flag set, the compiler error is issued though. So this doesn't really answer the question IMHO (unless I've missed something essential, and you're patient enough to enlighten me).

Comment: I've updated my code to pass the correct pointer. I'm still getting the error message using g++ 4.6.3, even if I add the `-std=c++0x` flag (`-std=c++11` and `-std=gnu++11` both are unrecognized)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's the different error, the one millsj's answer mentioned... See how there's no mention of linkage in the error message?

Comment: @Mokosha Sorry, this is implemented in GCC 4.7, not in 4.6. If you need this to work in GCC 4.6, you'll have to remove `static`.

Comment: I tried it with g++ 4.8.3 and `-std=gnu++11`, and the code works.

Answer (score 1):

`compressed_block` is expecting a `uint8_t**` as its first parameter, but you're giving it a `uint64_t*`

`static void compress_block(uint64_t* dst, const uint8_t* src, int rowBytes)`

This compiles and runs for me on VS2013.

Comment: This is entirely correct, but not what the question is asking about; fixing that won't get rid of the error GCC is reporting.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Only in C++11 mode.

Comment: @hvd That's set there (it's my default, this is the current standard)

Comment: I've updated my code to pass the correct variable, and updated the associated error message.